# require.context from svg file gives different result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I'm trying to create a react component for svg Icons so I'm trying to get context of the svg file with `require.context` like this

```
const myIcons = require.context('myIcons/', true, /^\.\/.*\.svg$/)
myIcons('./location.svg')
```

the problem is that I get the result as `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDo...`
and I expect it to return something more like `<svg ...><path ..></svg>` like it is in the svg file.

I tried to google it but I didn't find anything relevant.
thanks

Comment: fyi you may run into this problem: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/517 we've tried require.context in the same scenario (svg component with svg-sprite-loader), then resorted to simply exporting files via an index.js. It was causing issues w Flow too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced that issue not long ago, I found this loader for webpack
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader

install it and then define it inside the module loaders

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party, but if you don't want to (or can't cause your using something like [cra](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) you can also use [svg-react-loader](https://github.com/jhamlet/svg-react-loader). (easy to setup with cra, and without)

Then change your `require` statement to:

`const myIcons = require.context('!svg-react-loader!./myIcons/', true, /^\.\/.*\.svg$/)`

Comment: This was awesome just used @svgr/webpack instead of svg-react-loader which is already included in CRA
I would add to the answer how to render though as in this case would be: 
const Icon =  myIcons(path).default. and then in render func <Icon/>

Comment: @Christian thank you so much. I have **@svgr/webpack** too, but couldn't make it work. I was missing `.default`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the correct behaviour for the loader you've chosen. It has imported it as a base64 image. You can now place it in an image tag in the source.

```
<img src={myIcons('./location.svg')} />
```

If you wanted it where it will load in the SVG code itself, you'll have to find another loader. I ran into this a while back and couldn't find one myself, however that may have changed. It all depends on why you actually need the full svg code itself.

Another option, if you need the code, is to not have it as a svg file, but create a React component with the SVG code being returned.

```
export default () => (
    <svg>....</svg>
)
```

Comment: you should check @Danny's answer .. it works as expected.